# Ternary for img src, returned value or default value

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am a student building a simple web app for interacting with Google Books API. I have a random word being generated as the Google Books search parameter, which is returning in JSON correctly.

The problem is, some books do not have an "Author"/"Description"/"Image" parameter to return. For Author/Desc, I've accounted for this easily using a ternary, but the ternary isn't working out so well for an image source.

What I'm trying to achieve- IF the Google Books query has a value for Image, return that image: ELSE, return a default value of my choosing, in this case 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png'. I would rather not edit the HTML to achieve this.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this than through ternary. Can anyone advise?

`const testBookImg2` is the ternary of focus.

```
fetch (randomWord)
    .then (res => res.json())
    .then (obj => {
        console.log(obj)
        fetch (gbooks + obj[0])
        .then (res => res.json())
        .then (obj2 => {
            const testdesc1 = obj2.items[0].volumeInfo.description
            const testdesc2 = typeof(testdesc1) !== 'undefined' ? testdesc1 : 'No Description Provided'
            const testAuthor1 = obj2.items[0].volumeInfo.authors
            const testAuthor2 = typeof(testAuthor1) !== 'undefined' ? testAuthor1 : 'No Author'
            selectedBookDescription.innerText = testdesc2
            selectedBookAuthor.innerText = testAuthor2
            selectedBookTitle.innerText = obj2.items[0].volumeInfo.title

            const testBookImg1 = obj2.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
            const testBookLink = 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png'
            const testBookImg2 = typeof(testBookImg1) !== 'undefined' ? testBookImg1 : `${testBookLink}`

            selectedBookImage.src = testBookImg2
        })
    })
```

Comment: How about using `Object.hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: Can you spell that out for me? I am a student using training wheels.

Comment: My opinion regarding images is not to change the src element, but rather to load all images and hide the ones that shouldn't be seen

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty.

Comment: @WaisKamal Why do you think that will work better than testing the type?

Comment: What does `console.log(testBookImg1)` show?

Comment: @Barmar that was a suggestion, not an opinion.

Comment: I suspect that the value is an empty string or `null`, not `undefined`, so you should check for that in the ternary. Or just test for any falsey value.

Comment: `typeof` is not a function, it's an operator. That means that `typeof(testBookImg1) !== 'undefined'` is incorrect. Use `typeof testBookImg1 !== 'undefined'`. More on `typeof` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @muka.gergely typeof works in that way in the two other areas it's used in my code

Comment: @Barmar it logs the URL for the book image, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=F0tRAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api

Comment: @Barmar imageLinks.thumbnail does not exist if there is no image.

Comment: OK, then use it. It just seems odd, as it doesn't follow the [ECMAScript specifications](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator)

Comment: @muka.gergely I used it in the first two cases where it worked, but it's not working for the third case, hence my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no `imageLinks` property, so you get an error trying to read the `thumbnail` property of `undefined`.

Use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator to prevent this errors. It will assign the value of the property if it exists, or `undefined` if it doesn't exist or any of the intermediate properties don't exist.

```
const testBookImg1 = obj2.items[0]?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail;
const testBookLink = 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png';
const testBookImg2 = typeof testBookImg1 !== 'undefined' ? testBookImg1 : || testBookLink;
```

There's no need to use a template literal around `testBookLink`, since it's already a string.

This will set `testBookImg1` to `undefined` if any of the intermediate properties doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, the property does not exist, for instance here https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=peridot if you look at [0]/volumeInfo there is no 'imageLinks.thumbnail' key.

Comment: There's no `imageLinks` property at all, so you're getting an error trying to read a property of undefined.

Comment: exactly, i know. So, my question is, how can I return a default img src IF the value returns as undefined?

Comment: I already updated the answer.

Comment: I don't want to set testBookImg1 to undefined. If testBookImg1 is not defined, it already will return as undefined. if it returns undefined i want to set it to a default URL.

Comment: You do that with `testBookImg2`.

Comment: I tried setting the desired default value to a different variable, such as in my original post with ```const testBookLink``` but nothing I tried worked. I tried it as an interpolation (as is posted above), I tried ```testBookLink.src```, i tried a few other things but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I've updated the answer once more. I'm pretty sure this should work.

Comment: ```testBookImg1``` either exists OR is undefined. IF ```testBookImg1``` is undefined I want to set its URL value from ```undefined``` to some other URL imgsrc.

Comment: OK, if you want to use `testBookImg1` if it's an empty string, use the ternary. I've updated the answer.

Comment: what is the ```}``` after ```testBookLink```? Also, there is no "empty string" anywhere here.

Comment: It's just incomplete editing when I was removing the template literal after copying your code.

Comment: The empty string would be if there were a property like `thumbnail: ""`. I thought didn't want to use the `||` operator because that would replace this with your default. So I went back to the ternary so it would only replace `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle optional keys on objects:

```js
const obj = {
  key1: "val1",
}

const keyIn = (key, obj) => key in obj
const hasOwnProperty = (key, obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)

console.log('key1 in obj', keyIn('key1', obj))
console.log('key2 in obj', keyIn('key2', obj))
console.log('key1 hasOwnProperty with obj', hasOwnProperty('key1', obj))
console.log('key2 hasOwnProperty with obj', hasOwnProperty('key2', obj))
```

Also, you could use the `nullish coalescing operator - ??`:

```js
(function() {
  const testBookImg1 = 'valid string'
  const testBookLink = 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png'
  const testBookImg2 = testBookImg1 ?? testBookLink
  console.log('testBookImg2', testBookImg2)
})();

(function() {
  const testBookImg1 = undefined
  const testBookLink = 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png'
  const testBookImg2 = testBookImg1 ?? testBookLink
  console.log('testBookImg2', testBookImg2)
})();
```

---

### EDIT:

```js
// mock object
const obj2 = {
  items: [{
    volumeInfo: {
      imageLinks: {
        thumbnail: 'valid thumbnail src'
      }
    }
  }]
}

const testBookImg1 = obj2?.items[0]?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail
const testBookLink = 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png'
const testBookImg2 = testBookImg1 ?? testBookLink

console.log('testBookImg2', testBookImg2)

// the same, just a suffix added, so it doesn't crash:

const obj2_undefined = {
  items: [{
    volumeInfo: {}
  }]
}

const testBookImg1_undefined = obj2_undefined?.items[0]?.volumeInfo?.imageLinks?.thumbnail
const testBookLink_undefined = 'http://clipart-library.com/newimages/clip-art-books-15.png'
const testBookImg2_undefined = testBookImg1_undefined ?? testBookLink_undefined

console.log('testBookImg2_undefined', testBookImg2_undefined)
```

Comment: I am new to JS and can't understand how to turn your answer into a solution, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @Michael added an edit, so you see the exact way